# How to make a field required in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the simplest way to make a field required in Rails?

inquiry.rb:

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :email_id, :gender, :message, :mobile_number, :name
end
```

Comment: Your question should show that you researched this topic prior to asking the community for an answer. We programmers/developers should be inquisitive and searching for the answers before asking for assistance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the [presence validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence):

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

Answer (score 12):

[attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment. This is meant to protect sensitive attributes from being overwritten by malicious users tampering with URLs or forms. It has nothing to do with validations.

So, if you want to make the attribute presence mandatory, you have to use a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) in your model, like this one:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```