# How to make a file_field required before submit in erb Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, required

I'm trying to make a file_field required before the form is able to be submitted, using Rails and ERB, and I'm drawing a blank.

```
<%= form_for Image.new, html: {multipart: true} do |i| %>
  <%= i.label :description %>
  <%= i.text_field :description %>
  <%= i.file_field :image %>  <------**** This Line ****
  <%= i.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried using 'required' in various ways and searched the web but to no avail.  Is this something that I should seek to validate in the model instead?

My model is this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "600x600>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the list of suggested answers I found what I was looking for in this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398340/how-to-make-a-field-required-in-rails)

```
validates :image, :presence => true
```

I simply had to add that to my model and it doesn't let the form submit without an image attachment.

Comment: Or with html `<%= i.file_field :image, required: true %>`

Comment: It's ideal to validate on both levels. HTML as per: @EvanRoss, and the model as sanjsanj.

If you want to be even thorough, you can have a check on the controller function handling that submit request.

Comment: Both in the model and in the HTML is ideal so the User doesn't have to submit the form before they see it's required.