# Creating Required Fields for Website Forms (Simpleform)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add required fields for some forms on my website in order to better verify users

My intended solve: In looking online, I’ve tried a simple html fix within views>devise>registrations>`new.html.erb` and have started by editing the following code:

```
<div class="flex-col md:flex md:flex-row">
      <div class="form-group mb-3 pr-0 md:pr-2">
       <%= f.label :first_name %>
       <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "given-name", class: "form-control"%>
      </div>
```

I've attempted to implement the following:
`:required => :true` , `required: true` , `validates :first_name, presence => true` and other similar variations

I also tried changing in the `simple_form.rb` file:
`config.browser_validations = false`  to `= true` in order to enable validations on form fields.
Where I became stuck: None of these changes have broken the localhost, but also haven't changed anything. Each new account creation/sign up is able to be executed without entering a First Name. I can't tell if it's simpleform, html or otherwise.
Here's a few links I've tried to follow:

[How to make a field required in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398340/how-to-make-a-field-required-in-rails)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

[Rails: Attribute required for collection in simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235736/rails-attribute-required-for-collection-in-simple-form)
https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form (README)

[HTML5 'required' validation in Ruby on Rails forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541983/html5-required-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-forms)

EDIT: `User.rb` as requested:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # acts_as_token_authenticatable

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :rememberable, :confirmable, :async
  # :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]
  mount_uploader :logo, AvatarUploader

  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation, :registered_as

  has_many :wishlists
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy

  # callbacks
  after_create :assign_role
  after_save :sync_to_active_campaign_contact

  #
  def already_wishlist?(project)
    Wishlist.where(user_id: id, project_id: project.id).exists?
  end

  #
  # def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  #   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
  #   # where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  #   #   user.email = auth.info.email
  #   #   user.skip_password_validation = true
  #   #   # user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  #   #   # user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  #   #   # user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
  #   #   # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
  #   #   # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
  #   #   # user.skip_confirmation!
  #   # end
  # end

  # after_create :send_admin_mail
  # def send_admin_mail
  # ###Send email stuff here
  # end

  #
  def sync_to_active_campaign_contact
    return if Rails.env.development?
    if (confirmed_at.nil? ? false : confirmed_at <= Time.zone.now)

      begin
        fields = {
          'email' => email
        }

        ac_tags = ActiveCampaign.show_tags
        contact_tags = []
        if has_role?(:buyer)
          ac_fields = ActiveCampaign.show_fields
          field_id = ac_fields[:fields].find { |field| field[:title].casecmp?('buyer type') }[:id]
          fields.merge!({ fieldValues: [{
                          field: field_id,
                          value: buyer_type
                        }] }, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
          contact_tags << { contact: "id", tag: ac_tags[:tags].find { |tag| tag[:tag].casecmp?('buyer') }[:id] }
          contact_tags << { contact: "id", tag: ac_tags[:tags].find { |tag| tag[:tag].casecmp?(buyer_type) }[:id] }
        end
        # 1 user can have both roles, using else would crash the logic
        if has_role?(:developer)
          fields.merge!('orgname' => business_name)
          contact_tags << { contact: "id", tag: ac_tags[:tags].find { |tag| tag[:tag].casecmp?('developer') }[:id] }
        end

        ac_contact = ActiveCampaign.sync_contact(fields)
        ac_contact_id = ac_contact.dig(:contact, :id)

        contact_tags.each do |ct|
          contact_tag = ct.merge({ contact: ac_contact_id, tag: ct[:tag] })
          ActiveCampaign.create_contact_tag(contact_tag)
        end
      rescue StandardError
        logger.debug 'unable to sync with active campaign'
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  #
  def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation

    super
  end

  #
  def assign_role
    add_role registered_as
  end
end
```

EDIT 2: I'm also needing to include a required selection from an `f.select` option, while disabling the default 'Select One' option:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
            <%= f.label :buyer_type, "Which best describes you: " %>
            <%= f.select :buyer_type, ['Please Select','Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
          </div>
```

Comment: `required: true` option should be ok, what's the generated HTML?

Comment: @eux Sorry I'm very new to coding in general - what specifically do you need to see?

Comment: It's ok, I mean the final HTML for `first_name` field from the browser, similar to `<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>`.

Comment: This validation belongs in the `User` model (or whatever object is `registerable`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772931/how-do-i-validate-certain-fields-with-rails-devise-on-registration-only

Comment: @engineersmnky Looking in the `User` model, I can see a line with the following:

`}] }, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)`, what would be the way to change this, if this is the right spot?

Comment: @eux I believe it should be:

`<label class="string optional" for="user_first_name">First name</label>`

`<input autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="given-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="user[first_name]" id="user_first_name">` 
I just went 'Inspect Element' on the localhost and found the code corresponding to the first_name input field - I'm assuming that's what you were after?

Comment: @LJ-03 Yes, that's it, and if you add `required: true` option to `f.text_field` correctly, the `input` tag should have a `required` attribute: `<input ... required>`, then you could check whether you add the option successfully or the browser doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Post your User model by editing the original post

Comment: @engineersmnky done.

@eux good to know! I'm playing around with it now but nothing I'm doing is changing anything! Any ideas on how the `required: true` should be implemented into the `f.text_field`? I'm at a loss!

Comment: Just add this line `validates :first_name, presence: true`, that you already posted, to the User model

Comment: Does it matter where it goes? Or rather, where should it go?

Comment: @engineersmnky it worked!! Thank you so much!

Is there a way to also do this for a `f.select` feature? To ensure that one option (and not the 'Please Select' option) is chosen?

Comment: Edited post again to reflect `f.select` options question

Comment: Try `f.select :buyer_type, ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {prompt: true}, { class: "form-control"} %>`

Comment: @engineersmnky It didn't break it (hallelujah) but I'm still able to select the 'Please select' option when signing up.

Comment: Try `f.select :buyer_type, ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {include_blank: true}, { class: "form-control", required: 'required'} %>` instead

Comment: It works! Thank you so so much for this! Feel free to add the answer or I can do this

Comment: You can post your own answer if you'd like. BTW make sure when responding to comments to tag the User using @username so that the User is notified of your response

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks for that and all your help @engineersmnky

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @engineersmnky for the answers on this one:

For the `f.text_field`problem, adding:

```
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
```

to `user.rb` made my First and Last Name fields mandatory, not altering the html.

For the `f.select` problem was solved by just adjusting the html!

I've seen multiple fixes on stack overflow that have worked for people, but the one that worked for me was taking this:

```
<%= f.select :buyer_type, ['Please Select','Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

and changing it to this:

```
<%= f.select :buyer_type, ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {include_blank: "Please Select"}, { class: "form-control" , required: 'required'} %>
```